# How to chain\pipe commands onto remote PS-Session and automate manual entries

Tags: powershell, powershell-3.0, powershell-remoting

I need to chain or pipe commands onto remote PS Session on servers. How can I pass arguments or commands to power shell remote sessions and **automate the process of feeding command line arguments** ?

**If I log into a server locally** and open a command prompt and type the commands\parameters it works fine. This is for windows 2012 server.

Open a cmd prompt.

```
1.) cd "D:\Oracle\Servers\AppSrv01\bin"  //Type this in cmd prompt
2.) oraadmin.bat -user myuser -pwd mypwd //Type this in cmd prompt
oraadmin>oraadminctrl.invoke('clearlogs') //Type this in cmd prompt
oraadmin>oraadminctrl.invoke('stopserver') //Type this in cmd prompt
oraadmin> exit //This will exit the oraadmin in cmd prompt
3.)exit //Type this in cmd prompt, exits the cmd prompt
```

This works fine. Now I am trying to automate this in powershell by opening a session ($sess) object as below.

Tried this. But failed 'oraadminctrl.invoke' is not recognized as an internal or external command

```
$c = Invoke-Command -Session $sess {cmd.exe  /c “cd D:\Oracle\Servers\AppSrv01\bin && oraadmin -user admin -password mypassword && oraadminctrl.invoke('clearlogs') && oraadminctrl.invoke('stopserver')" }
```

**I just want to automate the process of feeding this username and password and running these commands one after other on the same command prompt process on the remote machine.** I am also open to start-process or other forms of invoke-command. **Writing a new batch file to be put on the server is not acceptable.** Any idea how to go about this ?

Comment: What is `oraadmin.bat`? Is that a home-brew script? Can it read from a file or take stdin?

Comment: I believe `oraadmin` is a some Oracle stuff. And lines between 2 and 3 are  `oraadmin` commands. That's why they are not recognized, Powershell knows nothing about how to pass these commands to `oraadmin`. Is there a way to pass them as parameters?

Comment: I don't understand what your question is. You seem to know how to execute a a couple of commands locally and in a remote session which is usually the hardest part. Btw, you are overloading the word automate. Powershell is a scripting language and it executes or invokes stuff.

Comment: @montonero...oraadmin.bat is a batch file which stops the server process. Can these be passed as parameters only ?

Comment: @AlexSarafian are you saying I cannot execute commands one after other like in a cmd prompt. I just want to open a cmd prompt in a remote session and execute commands one after other (something like script block) without manual intervention. Invoke command gives the option only to invoke "one" command.

Comment: Even if there is a way to pass parameters, can.t we  1.) "navigate to a folder " 2.) "run a bat file" , wait for it to finish 3.) "run next command" something like this in remote ps-session automatically ?.....

Comment: You need to take a step back and understand powershell remitting. As with a local session which retains state in its lifetime same applies for remote sessions. Begging the scenes a session and a process is started behind the scenes that the session variable gives you access to per invocation.

Comment: `incoke-command` accepts a script block which as a total is executed on the target remote session when provided. If the session is not provided then one is created per invocation, thus losing state among the calls. If the script block executes locally then it should execute remotely as well as long as the dependencies are matched

Comment: @DonWoodward Sorry, have no idea about how `oraadmin` works. Since you have an access to it you could try to look in its help about parameters.